# Encapsulation in backbone.js

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, encapsulation

This may be a general javascript or jQuery question- I'm using backbone.js and I'd like to have a private method in one class that can be used by subclasses. Is this possible?

```
var fooView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    this._privateFunc();
  },
  _privateFunc: function () {
  ...
  }
});

var subFooView = fooView.extend({
  initialize: function () {
    this.coolFunc();
    this._privateFunc();
  },
  coolFunc: function () {
  ...
  }
});
```

But then _privateFunc is not exposed to the outside world. I'm pretty new to encapsulation in javascript so forgive me if there's an obvious answer. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is more accurately called [protected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28computer_programming%29#Member_accessibility) rather than private accessibility. There's no way to directly implement this in JavaScript.

Your best bet is probably just to expose `_privateFunc` and use the convention that methods with underscores are only intended to be used by subclasses.

You could also implement [`__noSuchMethod__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod) in the parent and then check that the method is being called by a subclass and execute the protected method. However, this is a Mozilla extension.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean really *private*, you may try something like this...

```
var fooView;
(function(){
    var _privateFunc = function () {
        ...
    }

    fooView = Backbone.View.extend({
      initialize: function () {
        _privateFunc.call(this);
      }
    });
})();
```